# Beamer itemize doesn't work

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize, font-encodings

I have a document

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lithuanian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 
  \frame{
    \frametitle{sample}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item A
        \item B
    \end{itemize}
  }
\end{document}
```

It gives an error message

```
! Corrupted NFSS tables.
wrong@fontshape ...message {Corrupted NFSS tables}
                                                  error@fontshape else let f...
l.15   }
```

what's the problem?

Comment: The `\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}` is the problem.

Comment: I see, but I would like to know what's wrong with this and how should I solve my problem.

Comment: I suspect that the normal beamer item label somehow doesn't exist in your encoding. I can't try it myself because I don't have that encoding but try `\usepackage{paralist}` and then you can play around with different symbols by saying something like `\begin{itemize}[--]` or `[\textbullet]` or `[\bfseries\textendash]` or whatever. You can also set this document-wide with `\setdefaultitem{\textasteriskcentered}{}{}{}`. The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List will have more inspirations for what might look good.

Comment: There was no space left for the link: http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: There are *big* problems with the `L7x` encoding. I'll try to find a way out. You can "cure" the problem by saying `\usepackage{lmodern}`, but the font used will be the serif one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}% Now beamer didn't modify the math fonts
\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

    \frame{
    \frametitle{sample}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item A
        \item B
    \end{itemize}
  }

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are *big* problems with the L7x encoding. One way to cure them is to use

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lithuanian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{lmss} % sans serif text

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{sample}

\begin{itemize}
\item A $a+b$

\item B
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The definitions in `L7xenc.def` change many internal commands and it seems that `beamer` doesn't like it without explicitly choosing the fonts.